# Java: How to emulate a XInput gamepad/controller?

Tags: java, emulation, gamepad, xinput

I would like to emulate an XInput gamepad (controller) using Java. I've searched around the net but I couldn't really find any solution for my problem. Is it possible to simulate an XInput controller using Java?

I'm currently playing a game called Assetto Corsa, this game doesn't support the gamepad I'm currently using. This is why I would like to create a little program that simulates an XInput controller based on the current controller I'm using.

There are libraries available like `JXInput` that allow you to use XInput controllers in java, but I would like to have it the other way around. I couldn't find any solution for this on their pages.

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing can be done. In fact I used one few years back to play with a non XINPUT device. Search the internet.

Check this out
https://code.google.com/p/x360ce/

Comment: This program doesn't accept the gamepad either, strangely. The icon in the tab remains red. The program does successfully detect button presses wile assigning other keys, but the icon remains red. Thanks for your answer though, the problem is, that I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Hmm.. bad luck I guess. I think there should be a solution to your problem. I used this program with a cheap Chinese controller and it worked. You can look around forums and ask about the problem you faced with it. I found this page. Hope it helps....http://www.fairlyangrymike.com/how-tos/how-to-use-x360ce-with-your-pc-gamepad/

Comment: Yeah well, I tried to find the problem by searching on the net for hours, but I didn't succeed, sadly. Btw, I'm using a DualShock2 controller with a little adapter to connect it to my PC using USB.

Answer (score 0):

I tried x360ce using Assetto Corsa but once you load a track the frame pause every 1 or 2 seconds and it's completely unplayable for me. I play with a g27 and an old xbox type-s gamepad (no xinput) and the only way I found to use a non-xbox360 xinput controller is to set the controls to Wheel/Custom. I'll give you my settings it might fix it for you as well!

Steering settings:

Gamma: 1.8 -
Filter: 0.25 -
Speed Sensitivity: 0.05

Let's hope at a later date Normal gamepads will be supported as the game is surprisingly even without a wheel although less precise, especially for braking and for tight cornering.

Comment: The problem I'm having with Assetto Corsa is that I'm not able to decrease the sensitivity of the gamepad when it's recognized as a steering wheel. Now I'm thinking, I should try to decrease this sensitivity value manually in the game files. I'll give that a try right now..